# Python: What is wrong with subclassing a class from a parent package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to design package structures and class hierarchies within those packages in Python 3 projects, I'm constantly affected with circular import issues. This is whenever I want to implement a class in some module, subclassing a base class from a parent package (i.e. from some `__init__.py` from some parent directory).

Although I technically understand why that happens, I was not able to come up with a good solution so far. I found some threads here, but none of them go deeper in that particular scenario, let alone mentioning solutions.

In particular:

- Putting everything in one file is maybe not great. It potentially can be quite a mass of things. Maybe 90% of the entire project code?! Maybe it wants to define a common subclass of things (whatever, e.g. widget base class for a ui lib), and then just lots of subclasses in nicely organized subpackages? There are obvious reasons why we would not write masses of stuff in one file.
- Implementing your base class outside of `__init__.py` and just importing it there can work for a few places, but messes up the hierarchy with lots of aliases for the same thing (e.g. `myproject.BaseClass` vs. `myproject.foo.BaseClass`. Just not nice, is it? It also leads to a lot of boilerplate code that also wants to be maintained.
- Implementing it outside, and even not importing it in `__init__.py` makes those "fully qualified" notations longer everywhere in the code, because it has to contain `.foo` everywhere I use `BaseClass` (yes, I usually do `import myproject...somemodule`, which is not what everybody does, but should not be bad afaik).
- Some kinds of rather dirty tricks could help, e.g. defining those subclasses inside some kind of factory methods, so they are not defined at module level. Can work in a few situations, but is just terrible in general.

All of them are maybe okay in a single isolated situation, more as kind of a workaround imho, but in larger scale it ruins a lot. Also, the dirtier the tricks, the more it also breaks the services an IDE can provide.

All kinds of vague statements like 'then your class structure is probably bad and needs reworking' puzzle me a bit. I'm more or less distantly aware of some kinds of general good coding practices, although I never read "Clean Code" or similar stuff.

So, what is wrong with subclassing a class from a parent module from that abstract perspective? And if it is not, what is the secret workaround that people use in Python3? Is there a one, or is everybody basically dealing with one of the mentioned hacks? Sure, everywhere are tradeoffs to be made. But here I'm really struggling, even after many years of writing Python code.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this in the abstract. Please add some code that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: Subclassing shouldn't require circular imports.

Comment: Provide the structures would make everything more clear for everyone.

Comment: Its okay to subclass from a parent module but the parent module can't also import that submodule (not at the module level that is). If it tries, the submodule will attempt to import the parent to get the base class... but since the parent hasn't finished initialization (and is not yet added as a module in sys.path) you get a circular import. Is that what your problem is?

Comment: Like others, I suspect this is pointing out a real design tradeoff that can potentially trip people up and would be a good point of discussion. But it's hard to engage without more concrete examples.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you! I think I was a bit on the wrong way here in understanding the actual problem. It's essentially what @tdelaney said. So it's more complicated than what I initially wrote. It's allowed to do that, but you must not import the submodule in some parent packages. This is what I do here in one place for offering some convenience things. So, it's maybe not perfect, maybe the point where you could argue that my structure is not well designed (but, well, things are always a compromise). At least it's admittedly not true what I posted initially. And the workaround to use a few function level `import`s is maybe kind of okay in that place.